# A relation between an integral domain and its integral closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

Let $D$ be an integral domain and $\overline{D}$ be the integral
closure of $D$. Is there any condition equivalent to the property
that there exists $0\neq x\in D$ such that
$x\overline{D}\subseteq D$?

Note that if $D=\overline{D}$, then the above property
always holds.

Answer (score 0):

If $D$ is noetherian, this is equivalent to the statement that $D \subset \overline D$ is a finite extension.

Clearly, if that extension is finite, you just take $x$ to be the product of all denominators among generators of $\overline D$. No noetherian assumption needed.

On the other hand, if $x\overline D \subset D$ holds, you have $\overline D \subset \frac{1}{x}D$ and the latter is a noetherian $D$-module if $D$ is noetherian.

Comment: For example assume that  $\overline D=D [\frac {r}{s}] $. Thus, $x:=s $, $\frac {r^2}{s^2} \in\overline D$ , but $x\frac {1}{s^2}\not \in D $.

Comment: What is your point? Are you implying I am wrong? Then, you are wrong I am afraid. If $\frac{r}{s}$ is integral over $D$, then some power of that fraction can be generated by using denominators with lower exponents...Also you seem to miss the difference between a generating set as a module and as algebra.